# Reading blob audio data in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wav, mediarecorder

I need to send the raw audio data that a user records in the browser to an API.

I'm sending the raw blob object via POST to my Rails backend. It looks like this when recieved.

```
{"blob"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f83ad01a7d8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/cc/f7_d06hs6psbcxl87nwzsplr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20201021-933-1xu271c>, @original_filename="blob", @content_type="audio/wav", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"blob\"; filename=\"blob\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/wav\r\n">, "controller"=>"audios", "action"=>"interview"}
```

How can I read the actual data and extract it (without headers) to send to the external service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.3/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html) looks similar to an [IO object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/IO.html), so you can probably just:

```rb
uploaded_file = params["blob"]
raw_string = uploaded_file.read # do what you want with the raw data
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! That seems to work. Unfortunately it comes through as a bunch of crazy non-ascii characters so...on to the next challenge

Comment: Yeah of course, that's what raw binary data is -- it's not intended to be human readable.